# I installed Linux Build Support, but I need an archive to build, how can I get this?

Tags: unity, build-process

I`m building a game for Mac, Windows and Linux, I builded the Windows and Mac game, but in Linux, says that need a x86_64 archive, like the image shows, what do I do?[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's not the new build file it's trying to create, rather than a dependency file it's asking you to locate?

Answer (score 1):

This is Unity asking where you want it to put the built application and what to name it.